# Regex - Check first character of every line

Tags: regex

I am searching for a regex that would do the following:

1. Check if the first character of the line is a - or :
2. Check the succeeding characters of the line and it should be alphanumeric and whitespace are acceptable. There are maximum 10 characters per line.
3. Should impose 5 max lines

I have been working on the following regex:
`^[^:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$`   --> for nos. 1 & 2 condition. However, it seems like it is not working .

Then for the number of lines, I searched at https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s10.html . The regex below would check the number of lines.

```
^(?:[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n?|\n)){0,4}[^\r\n]*$
```

I don't know how to combine all the conditions I mentioned in a regex. It's my first time working on it.

Not Acceptable. There is - in 2nd line

Hello01

-Hello01

Hello0

Hello03

Hello04

Not Acceptable. More than 5 Lines

Hello01

-Hello01

Hello02

Hello03

Hello04

Hello05

Acceptable. No - or : in first character of the line

Hello01

Hello02

Hello03

Hello04

Hello05

Comment: Maybe `^[:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}(?:\r?\n[:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}){0,4}$`?

Comment: my bad, the first condition should be - The first character should not be a - or :

Comment: Then `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}(?:\r?\n[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}){0,4}$`? The first char is alphanumeric here.

Comment: Hm. Do you have an example of valid data? What would the 1st character be if not an hyphen or colon?

Comment: Or, `^[^\r\n:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}(?:\r?\n[^\r\n:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}){0,4}$`. Does either work?

Comment: But it doesn't make sense. Why do you want to make sure that the 1st char isn't an hyphen or colon? What is the allowed characters? Only alphanumeric? If so, why not just check the lenght for alphanumeric is 10? Also, your current sample data does not contain lines of 10 characters. So do you also want to rephrase that requirement?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the last regex worked for me.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^\r\n:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}(?:\r?\n[^\r\n:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}){0,4}$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\r\n:-]` - any char that is not CR, LF, `:` and `-`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}` - zero to nine alnum chars
- `(?:\r?\n[^\r\n:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}){0,4}` - zero to four occurrences of

  - `\r?\n` - CRLF or LF ending
  - `[^\r\n:-][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}` - any char that is not CR, LF, `:` and `-` and then zero to nine alnum chars
- `$` - end of string.